# Spring - Ingres RDBMS support in sql-error-codes.xml error code mapping file

Tags: java, spring, error-handling, ingres

I have a Java project connecting to an Ingres database and using the Spring Framework. This issue is related to the error codes list configuration.

According to [Spring Framework API](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/support/SQLErrorCodesFactory.html):

> Class SQLErrorCodes: JavaBean for
>   holding JDBC error codes for a
>   particular database. Instances of this
>   class are normally loaded through a
>   bean factory.
>
> Used by Spring's
>   SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.
>   The file "sql-error-codes.xml" in this
>   package contains default SQLErrorCodes
>   instances for various databases.

The default file is bundled in spring.jar, does not include error codes associated with Ingres RDBMS and it’s location is `org/springframework/jdbc/support/sql-error-codes.xml`

This document "[Ingres 2006 SQL Reference Guide](http://downloads.ingres.com/download/sql.pdf)", in Appendix D: SQLSTATE Values and Generic Error Codes, contains the complete list of Ingres RDBMS error codes.

The only relevant sample of sql-error-codes.xml file containing Ingress error codes is this [one](http://jira.springframework.org/browse/SPR-5444):

Quote:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN 2.0//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans-2.0.dtd">

<!--
    - Default SQL error codes for well-known databases.
    - Can be overridden by definitions in a "sql-error-codes.xml" file
    - in the root of the class path.
    -
    - If the Database Product Name contains characters that are invalid
    - to use in the id attribute (like a space) then we need to add a property
    - named "databaseProductName"/"databaseProductNames" that holds this value.
    - If this property is present, then it will be used instead of the id for
    - looking up the error codes based on the current database.
    -->
<beans>
    <bean id="INGRES" class="org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodes">
        <property name="useSqlStateForTranslation">
            <value>true</value>
        </property>
        <property name="badSqlGrammarCodes">
            <value>22000,26000,42000,42500,42501,50000,5000A</value>
        </property>
        <property name="invalidResultSetAccessCodes">
            <value>24000</value>
        </property>
        <property name="dataIntegrityViolationCodes">
            <value>23500,23501,23502</value>
        </property>
        <property name="dataAccessResourceFailureCodes">
            <value>08001</value>
        </property>
        <property name="cannotAcquireLockCodes">
            <value>5000R</value>
        </property>
        <property name="cannotSerializeTransactionCodes">
            <value>40001</value>
        </property>
        <property name="deadlockLoserCodes">
            <value>40P01</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Can anyone suggest a more up-to-date and complete version?

Comment: So you want a more complete error code mapping, or you do you want to know how to use the above mapping?

Comment: For start, I want a more complete code mapping, if possible from a reputable source. Next, I will need to "merge" it with the one already present in spring.jar but that is another matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 9.3 SQLState codes can be obtained from [docs.ingres.com](http://docs.ingres.com/Ingres/9.3/OpenSQL%20Reference%20Guide/sqlstatevaluesgenericerrorcodes.htm). From speaking with the person who submitted the [JIRA ticket](http://jira.springframework.org/browse/SPR-5444) there have been no further updates. Most errors are handled with the appropriate exception type. Similar to the PostgreSQL profile.

Answer (score 0):

Extracted from the Ingres 9.3 documentation for you the SQL State Values and Generic Error Codes

[Ingres 9.3 SQL Reference Guide - Appendix C: SQLSTATE Values and Generic Error Codes](http://drop.io/ingres93sqlerrorref)

Comment: I already mentioned the Appendix containing the error codes - but I need the file sql-error-codes.xml as required by Spring Framework

Comment: Yeah but you referenced Ingres 2006 instead of 9.3

Comment: The error codes are much the same between releases, especially for the SQL State which is more generic than the native Ingres error codes.

Comment: Correct and btw I don't think you can use the sql-error-codes.xml to handle native error codes